# Split multiple data from single cell into multiple cells Excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to achieve as shown in the screenshot below? in the first screenshot, the data is all in cell A2 with line breaks.

I would like for it to break down and follow the format as shown in screenshot 2?

I have tried split function but it is not giving the accurate answer and i think a single split will not be use to break it according to the headers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

I have attached a google Sheet for an example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kTw2srIZHrgrrXMm3dj_7D6CrUHWrZCK97aAzyQvaag/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You can work with [`FILTERXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194). Substitute both colon and newline characters and pull according to your headers (or position rather...every 2nd element).

Comment: What is this `SPLIT` function and what kind of result is it giving you.  *(I am not aware of a `SPLIT` function in Excel 2016`)*

Comment: Thank you very much i tried to apply but do not understand how. @JvdV

Comment: =SPLIT(A2,":") i used this but result was not accurate. @ Ron Rosenfeld

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formula solution

In `B2`, formula copied across right and all copied down :

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($A2,B$1&":","<r/>"),CHAR(10),"</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[r]["&COUNTIF($B$1:B$1,B$1)&"]"),"")
```

[image]

Comment: There are some cells which does not populate the result and comes empty @bosco_yip can you please visit the attached sheet again

Comment: Please indicate which cells give empty, however the formula is used for Excel worksheet and don't suit for  Google Sheet.

Comment: Yes i know and using in Excel rather than in google sheet. I have updated the new data in Google Sheets which comes empty

Comment: Without knowing your new data information, it is difficult to give any help.

Comment: Yes i know that's why i have updated the data (which comes empty) in above attached google sheet link.

Comment: You still haven't reply which cells come empty.

Comment: Right. If you apply given formula into the data which is available in google Sheets all cell will return empty not a single cell. Please copy the data from google sheets to MS Excel then you will see all cell will return empty. Please see the picture as well https://ibb.co/vzWpwkf @bosco_yip

Comment: Your attached screenshot  is a totally different layout in compare with your original layout. The main different is your new layout do not have line breaker CHAR(10) in between line & line. This is the main reason of the formula don't work & return empty.

Comment: I understand your point but i just use wrap text nothing else. If i again use wrap text then format will be recover. Let me update second picture just for the clearance. There must be issue with data or formula where it does not work for some of the data. Please see https://ibb.co/c1KxVXc why yellow highlighted comes empty whereas other comes with data. those data which comes empty added in google Sheets. @bosco_yip

Comment: It is worked in about 90% come with data. the 10% failure reasons mostly are the inconsistent of the source data. I do not have any further comment and good luck.

Comment: No Problem thank you for the help @@bosco_yip

Answer (score 0):

Method1:

Step1: Go to the Data tab and use 'Text to column' with the delimiter **:**

Step2: Use =`TRANSPOSE(E9:F10)`function. Note- Office 365 Transpose fills the array automatically.

Method2: Use power query SPLIT function.

=`Text.Split([Column1],":")` and `Table.Transpose`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the Power Query Solution @santhosha